# R package ltm: How to manipulate title on item response category characteristic curve plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, psychometrics

I have conducted an IRT analysis using package [ltm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/index.html) in R 2.10.

```
fit1 <- grm(data)
```

When producing plots of item response characteristic curves (ICCs),

```
plot(fit1)
```

the text "Item response characteristic curves - Item:NAME" is printed as the main title of each plot. NAME is substituted with the actual name of the items in the dataset.

A common practice is to present all the individual ICC plots on a single page, and then all that is needed in the title of each plot is the NAME (or at the most "Item: NAME").

I have not been able to achieve this, if I create a vector with the actual item names (e.g. v1, v2, v3...Vn) they are all used as the title in each of the plots.

What I would like to achieve is to have the title of each plot simply read "Item: NAME" where NAME is replaced/pasted with the names of the actual variables in my data.

The variable names themselves are available in the coefficients `fit1` object, and can be retrieved with `names(fit1$coefficients)`.

Anyone have a suggestion for how to achieve this?

Reproducible sample (thanks @Chi)

```
dat <- Science[c(1,3,4,7)]
fit1 <- grm(dat)
par(mfrow = c(2,2))
plot(fit1)
```

This plots each of the four ICCs on the same device, but all titles contain the abovementioned text that I wish to remove. It also contains the text "Item: NAME" (i.e. comfort, environment, work, benefit) which I would like to retain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the argument `main=` when calling `plot()`, e.g.

```
dat <- Science[c(1,3,4,7)]
fit1 <- grm(dat)
plot(fit1, items=1, main=paste("Item", names(dat)[1], sep=": "))
```

See `help(plot.grm)`.

Also, you can embed all ICC curves in the same figure by using `par()`, e.g.

```
opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in 1:4)
  plot(fit1, items=i, main=paste("Item", names(dat)[i], sep=": "))
par(opar)
```

Comment: @Chi Thanks! This works, but means I have to plot each item individually (and combine them with par). What I was hoping for was to simply obtain the same result by using par(mfrow=c(3,3)) and simply plot(fit1, 'some edits to 'main='") which gives me all the plots (9 in my case).

Comment: @Tormod I'm afraid you can't. Look at the R code for that function (just type `plot.grm` at the R prompt or `edit(plot.grm)`) near line 52 and 91: Dimitri R. automatically prefixes the title if missing and append "Item".

Comment: @Chi Thanks again! Still, your solution works fine so I am still able to achieve what I want, albeit with a few more lines of code.

Comment: @Tormod The same applies for the `eRm` package. It's difficult to provide users with both a friendly and generic interface :(

Comment: @Tormod It's just my humble opinion: Would it be troublesome if you created another function like plot2.grm which does not prefix the title? If you are going to use the form a lot, it would be better considering simplicity of the code!!! (+1) for nice work

Comment: @KHKim For quick edits (i.e., lasting for the current session), the function can be edited online using your preferred editor with `fixInNamespace(plot.grm, pos="package:ltm")`.